# "Html canvas" image quality is low for some reason

Tags: javascript, html, image

Picture quality is very good. but when i upload the image to canvas the quality goes down. but on many sites this is not the case. 7 megabyte image is changing to 54 kilobytes on canvas

[image: javascript code]

the image and text are not coming out in good quality

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+canvas+image+quality+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Do NOT post PICTURES of code

Comment: what's your canvas width and height?